# io.connect(); is not initialized , node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am making my project with the help of `http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/node-js-better-performance-with-socket-io-and-dot--net-35076` this guide...

my index.js is

```
var express = require('express');
//var dot = require('dot').template;
//var fs = require('fs');
var sio = require('socket.io');

var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

var posts = [
    { avatar: 'av1.gif', author: 'Jane Doe', text: 'Lorem ipsum ' },
    { avatar: 'av2.png', author: 'John Doe', text: 'Nam interdum'},
    { avatar: 'av3.jpg', author: 'Jeffrey Doe', text: 'Ineger at.' }
];

app.use(express.static('./static'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());

//var postTemplate = dot(fs.readFileSync('./post.dot'));

app.get('/getpost', function (req, res) {
    res.end(postTemplate(posts[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]));
});
```

my main.js file is

```
var postTemplate = function (it) { var out='<div class="post"><div class="some-fblike-nested-div-one"><div class="some-another-nested-div"><div class="nested-div-for-avatar another-long-class"><img src="'+( it.avatar )+'"></div><div class="one-more-div-for-text-here with-some-long classes-to-format-it"><p><span class="author-also-wants-to have-some-fancy-span"><b>'+( it.author )+'</b>:<br></span>'+( it.text )+'</p></div></div></div></div>';return out; }

var socket = io.connect();


$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        socket.emit('getpost');
    });
});


socket.on('getpost', function (data) {
    $('button').after(postTemplate(data));
});
```

the problem is that function in the main.js

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

is never working,,,, and the error on console of browser is 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined` ... any help is aprreciable... please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the socket.io script in your page/response.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

This is required by browser to use the socket.io-client API to connect to the socket.io server.

Comment: @Jatt.net is the io.connect executed on node.js or browser ?

Comment: while i am writing io.connect, after io.  in intelligence there is no method connect seen. and the whole line is not documented,,, the main problem here is that in main.js there is no io method is appeared

Comment: @Jatt.net You wrote the code, where have you defined it. Your postTemplate is in main.js which you call from app.get in node.js. Why does it have jquery code ?

Comment: create our discussion room please.. we can talk realtimely

Comment: are you there @user568109

Comment: @Jatt.net Cannot chat at the moment. Have to reach home. Can you tell the directory structure, for your server.

Comment: directory structure?  sorry :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47011/discussion-between-jatt-net-and-user568109)